# Meaning of D train?

Tags: meaning-in-context

On instagram there is this piece about John Michel Basquiat.

It says "He got his start painting grafitti on the D train".

What does D train mean?

Answer (score 2):

In some cities, routes on the mass transit system are identified using letters and/or numbers. New York is an example of this (you can see the map [here](http://web.mta.info/maps/submap.html)), and is likely the system that was referred to, as Basquiat comes from New York. The normal usage in New York is to call a subway route by its letter or number, followed by the word *train* rather than *route*, so one thus refers to *the D train* instead of *route D*.

Answer (score 0):

It means a train line identified by the letter D, specifically [the D Line of the Metropolitan Transit Agency of New York City](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/dline.htm), where Basquiat lived:

[image]